# Cardinal of Set of All Finite Subset of $\Bbb N$

Tags: cardinals

Let X be the set of all finite subset of $\Bbb N$. Then

let the set $S = \{\xi \mid \xi \approx X, \xi \leqslant 2^X\}$ then

Card(X) is the least element of S.

First, I can't start with how to exhaust all the element of S.

Any advice?

Comment: Is the question just to find the cardinality of the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb N$? Not sure what we need all the initial ordinal mumbo jumbo (I assume that's why you wrote down about $S$?) Here's a hint: it's countable. If you can find a bijection from the naturals then you know $\omega$ is the smallest ordinal $\approx$ to it, so $Card(X)  = \omega$ by the initial ordinal definition.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  had shown that X is countable, thus card(X) $\le \aleph_0$ now, I want to show that card(X) $\ge \aleph_0$. Any suggetions?

Comment: That's the easy direction. $X$ isn't finite, is it? Find an injective function $\aleph_0 \to X.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen oh.. that's hard.. how could one deal with the infinite case of $\Bbb N$.. and maps it to the set of finite subset of $\Bbb N$

Comment: Associate to each integer a unique finite subset of the integers. There's a painfully obvious way to do this. It's one of those things that might be hard to come up with but once you find it you'll kick yourself for not thinking of it sooner.

Comment: Also I'm curious how you did $|X| \ge \aleph_0 $ without finding a bijection. If you found a bijection $X\leftrightarrow \mathbb N$ (which proves $|X|=\aleph_0$) and not (say) an injective function $X\to \mathbb N$ (which would only show $|X| \ge \aleph_0$), you're done. But in any event, as I said before, it's really easy to find an injective function $\mathbb N \to X.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{N} \approx \mathbb{N}^2$ should be classical.
(e.g. using the bijection $f(n,m) = (2n+1)2^m.)$

By induction: $\mathbb{N} \approx \mathbb{N}^k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This only uses that $\approx$ is an equivalence relation.

The set of (non-empty) finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ has an injection into the set 
$T = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{N}^k$, mapping each finite set to its unique ordered tuple in $T$ when writing it in increasing order. A countable union of countable sets is countable. It follows that $S$ is at most $\aleph_0$ (and as least $\aleph_0$ too, mapping $n$ to $\{n\}$ is an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ into $S$.). So it's exactly $\aleph_0$ by Cantor-Bernstein.

Comment: I had considered too many approahces.. but yours the most concise one. thx..

Comment: isn't the empty set also included in the set of finite subset of $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Adding one element to a countable set leaves it countable.@Daschin

Comment: Also, the empty set is covered by $k=0$ in the union of $T$

Comment: one more question. what I wonder is, how could be sure of one could find such function that maps n to {n} including the case of n is infinite?

Comment: $n$ is a single natural number, it cannot be infinite.